# Is there a way to have formula for first row automatically populate the cells below?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I use this formula to print a `yes` in a cell if there are numbers `>0` in the range `$T4:$AE4` OR in the range `$AG4:$AR4`.

```
=IF(OR(COUNTIF($T4:$AE4,">0"),COUNTIF($AG4:$AR4,">0")),"yes","")
```

Then I drag the formula down (as I need this for a 1000 rows).
Is there a way to just have the formula for the first row and automatically populate the cells below if the rows below match the criteria?

I tried with an `ARRAYFORMULA` but it's not working..

```
=IF(OR(ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF($T4:$AE,">0")),ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF($AG4:$AR,">0"))),"yes","")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(COLUMN(T4:AE)^0,TRANSPOSE(if(ISNUMBER(T4:AE),T4:AE,0))))+TRANSPOSE(MMULT(COLUMN(AG4:AR)^0,TRANSPOSE(if(ISNUMBER(AG4:AR),AG4:AR,0))))>0,"yes",""))
```

---

**Explanation**

`mmult` is used to make sums of $T4:$AE and $AG4:$AR

`ISNUMBER` is to convert all not numeric values into numbers in order to use only numbers in `mmult` function.

`COLUMN(AG4:AR)^0` will give a column of ones (1,1,1,1,1) -- just what we need for `mmult` function.

`Transpose` is used because in [`[mmult]`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094292?hl=en) function:

> the number of columns for matrix1 must equal the number of rows for
>   matrix2

so we need to transpose part of formula.

---

By the way, here's this formula but transformed to count matches of the word "word":

```
=ArrayFormula(if(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(COLUMN(T4:AE)^0,TRANSPOSE(--(T4:AE="word"))))+TRANSPOSE(MMULT(COLUMN(AG4:AR)^0,TRANSPOSE(--(T4:AE="word"))))>0,"yes",""))
```

As you can see, the principles of the formula can be used to match `count` logic.

Comment: it's because mmult functions takes ranges in a specific way, I've added more details to the answer